# Grouping a dataframe and applying tuple

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` of the following form:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({('a','A'):[3,4,5,6],
               ('a','B'):[1,1,3,5],
               ('b','A'):[9,7,0,3],
               ('b','B'):[2,0,1,6]
              })
```

which looks like this:

```
    a     b   
   A  B  A  B
0  3  1  9  2
1  4  1  7  0
2  5  3  0  1
3  6  5  3  6
```

I group it by the second level using the following command:

```
grouped = df.groupby(level=1,axis=1)
```

And get:

```
Group  A 
________
   a  b
   A  A
0  3  9
1  4  7
2  5  0
3  6  3


Group  B 
________
   a  b
   B  B
0  1  2
1  1  0
2  3  1
3  5  6
```

How can I take each group's two columns and put them into a tuple row-wise and convert that into a new `DataFrame`. Basically I'm trying to get at this:

```
   A      B  
0  (3,9)  (1,2)
1  (4,7)  (1,0)
2  (5,0)  (3,1)
3  (6,3)  (5,6)
```

I've been trying

```
grouped.apply(lambda x : tuple(x))
```

But it doesn't do the job and instead gives me tuples of column names. Is there a simple way to do this without resorting to `for` loops?

Comment: Your desire not to use loops suggests you are interested in performance. If you are interested in performance, then you should not place tuples in the DataFrame since tuples are not a native NumPy dtype. Arithmetical operations in a DataFrame will always be quicker if you stick with NumPy dtypes (such as `int64`s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
grouped.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([tuple(i) for i in x.values]))
```

Comment: I think you need a `)` at the end

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick:

```
grouped.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x.itertuples(index=False))))
```